# vb.net how to use shift for selecting multiple checkbox

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datagridview

How to change state of multiple `CheckBoxes`  in `DataGridView` by pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd> key and select the checkbox.

Is it possible to do it in `vb.net`?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm using datagridview and all checkbox is set to true..all i want is to change the state in multiple selection by clicking the 1st checkbox and press shift then click again for faster changing state.

Comment: I have a solution that works if you leave the cell after you Shift-Clicked. Is that feasible for you?

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of how that could be accomplished. For this example, I just created a datagridview with two columns, one text and one checkbox, and added 5 rows to it. The key is the datagridview_click event. When that event gets called, it will check if the shift key was being held down with the click. If it was, it will uncheck every datagridviewcheckboxcell in your selection:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim c1 As New DataGridViewTextBoxColumn
    DataGridView1.Columns.Add(c1)
    Dim c2 As New DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn
    DataGridView1.Columns.Add(c2)

    For i As Integer = 1 To 5
        DataGridView1.Rows.Add("test" & i.ToString, True)
    Next i
End Sub

Private Sub DataGridView1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.Click
    If My.Computer.Keyboard.ShiftKeyDown Then
        For Each cell As DataGridViewCell In DataGridView1.SelectedCells
            If TypeOf cell Is DataGridViewCheckBoxCell Then cell.Value = False
        Next
        DataGridView1.RefreshEdit()
    End If
End Sub
```